# Change input variable in a function

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, scoping

I'd like to write a function, that would take a matrix as an input parameter and would change it by multiplying one of its rows by a factor.

I try to do it in the following way:

```
matrix=Table[i*j,{i,Range@2},{j,Range@2}]
MultiplyRowByFactor[m_,factor_,iRow_]:=Module[{},m[[All,iRow]]*=factor;m]
MultiplyRowByFactor[matrix,2,1]
```

and get an error message

```
Set::setps: "{{1,2},{2,4}} in the part assignment is not a symbol. "
```

Of course, if I change the matrix outside of the function:

```
matrix[[All,1]]*=2;
matrix
```

everything works as expected.

What is the problem and how can I write a function to modify a matrix "in place"?

Comment: You need to set `HoldFirst` attribute for your function. Also, do not use `Module` if you are not going to scope anything, it will only slow you down.

Comment: @Kuba, thank you for the comment and for the links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent `m` from evaluating to its value, use the following command:

```
SetAttributes[MultiplyRowByFactor, HoldFirst];
```

Just once, right after the declaration of `MultiplyRowByFactor`. Now the first argument of this function, which is just `m`, is held, and everything works.