# Editing the function argument

Tags: functions, hold, arguments

I'd like to construct a function, that changes its own input. The code

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst];   l={1,2,3};
f[l_List] := Module[{i}, For[i=1, i<=Length@l, i++, Print[i]; l[[i]]=1;]];
f[l];   l
```

returns `{1,2,3}` instead of `{1,1,1}`. What am I doing wrong?

[This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17767/how-to-modify-function-argument) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46963/change-input-variable-in-a-function) post did not help.

Comment: Hmm, strange, if instead I write `f[l_]:=...`, then it works. :/

Comment: Yes, because the `HoldFirst` attribute means that the `Symbol` is passed, not an expression with a head `List`.

Comment: Aha, so the solution is to always omit `_List`?

Comment: `Do[l[[i]] = 1, {i, Length@l}]` seems like better code for the body of `f`.  (I realize it's just a test example, but `For` is rarely used by *Mathematica* programmers.)

Comment: Yes, as you discovered (by your first comment).

Comment: You can also use `l_?ListQ` which will test without the `Hold`